# How to build a grouped bar graph for comparison from data that is denormalized

Tags: google-sheets, pivot-table, bar-chart

I have the following raw data that compares benchmark times for a few experiments:

[image]

And I would like to generate a grouped bar chart that looks like this but the raw data isn't formatted correctly for the chart to generate the data correctly (I put the data in the table manually):

[image]

Is it possible to generate the desired chart from the raw data directly? If not, is it possible to write some kind of query to format the data correctly so the graph is generated like this?

Here's my example sheet: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/e/2PACX-1vTtI5DQ9s2egOn19ykflkLMPCZQhNllrPQh9ia2L6zar0GQ8nvBpgh1tjzq5REgH_nZc0qZKfF3_8HS/pubhtml

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this formula to re-organize the data in order to get the expected graph design.

```
=query({A:C},"Select Col2, sum(Col3) Where Col2 is not null group by Col2 pivot Col1")
```

[image]